# Beam Runner hooks for Throughput-based autoscaling

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm curious if anyone can point me towards greater visibility into how various Beam Runners manage autoscaling.  We seem to be experiencing hiccups during both the 'spin up' and 'spin down' phases, and we're left wondering what to do about it.  Here's the background of our particular flow:

1- Binary files arrive on gs://, and object notification duly notifies a PubSub topic.
2- Each file requires about 1Min of parsing on a standard VM to emit about 30K records to downstream areas of the Beam DAG.
3- 'Downstream' components include things like inserts to BigQuery, storage in GS:, and various sundry other tasks.
4- The files in step 1 arrive intermittently, usually in batches of 200-300 every hour, making this - we think - an ideal use case for autoscaling.

What we're seeing, however, has us a little perplexed:

1- It looks like when 'workers=1', Beam bites off a little more than it can chew, eventually causing some out-of-RAM errors, presumably as the first worker tries to process a few of the PubSub messages which, again, take about 60 seconds/message to complete because the 'message' in this case is that a binary file needs to be deserialized in gs.
2- At some point, the runner (in this case, Dataflow with **jobId 2017-11-12_20_59_12-8830128066306583836**), gets the message additional workers are needed and real work can now get done.  During this phase, errors decrease and throughput rises.   Not only are there more deserializers for step1, but the step3/downstream tasks are evenly spread out.
3-Alas, the previous step gets cut short when Dataflow senses (I'm guessing) that enough of the PubSub messages are 'in flight' to begin cooling down a little. That seems to come a little too soon, and workers are getting pulled as they chew through the PubSub messages themselves - even before the messages are 'ACK'd'.

We're still thrilled with Beam, but I'm guessing the less-than-optimal spin-up/spin-down phases are resulting in 50% more VM usage than what is needed.  What do the runners look for beside PubSub consumption?  Do they look at RAM/CPU/etc??? Is there anything a developer can do, beside ACK a PubSub message to provide feedback to the runner that more/less resources are required?

Incidentally, in case anyone doubted Google's commitment to open-source, I spoke about this very topic with an employee there yesterday, and she expressed interest in hearing about my use case, especially if it ran on a non-Dataflow runner!  We hadn't yet tried our Beam work on Spark (or elsewhere), but would obviously be interested in hearing if one runner has superior abilities to accept feedback from the workers for THROUGHPUT_BASED work.

Thanks in advance,
Peter

CTO, 
ATS, Inc.

Comment: Please see answer below about how autoscaling sizing is usually calculated. I looked at your job. As you mentioned it is an atypical case where you have very low volume of bytes and records and each record takes lot of processing. When volume is low, it can have large variation in backlog seconds calculation (backlog / throughput) since throughput is extremely small.

That said, your job generally looks ok upscales to 3 workers when there is load and downscales after that. I don't see it downscaling too early. Can you point to a specific time where you expect unexpected downscaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally streaming autoscaling in Dataflow works like this :

- **Upscale**: If the pipeline's backlog is more than a few seconds based on current throughput, pipeline is upscaled. Here CPU utilization does not directly affect the amount of upsize. Using CPU (say it is at 90%), does not help in answering the question 'how many more workers are required'. CPU does affect indirectly since pipelines fall behind when they they don't enough CPU thus increasing backlog.
- **Downcale**: When backlog is low (i.e. < 10 seconds), pipeline is downcaled based on current CPU consumer. Here, CPU does directly influence down size.

I hope the above basic description helps.

Due to inherent delays involved in starting up new GCE VMs, the pipeline pauses for a minute or two during resizing events. This is expected to improve in near future.

I will ask specific questions about the job you mentioned in description.

Comment: Raghu, thanks for the insight into how Dataflow throughout works.  We may have an edge case, but our issue is clearly RAM-related (though the number of GC out-of-memory errors have declined since I posted the question -- might be a coincidence.)  It would be nice if Beam/Dataflow could account for (few) PubSub events requiring more RAM for tasks, since otherwise 'Upscale/Downscale' won't happen fast enough.  We'll continue to leave the jobId running, and report back from time to time.  Thanks again.